# What does (Sass::SyntaxError in Pages#home) mean in RoR?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When I go to run my app, I start the server using rails server from the master folder of my app.  when I use 127.0.0.1:3000 to view my apps homepage, it gives me this error (Sass::SyntaxError in Pages#home); why am I getting this error?

***Here's what I'm getting in my command line***:

```
Doesha@DOESHA-PC ~/Desktop/pinteresting (master)
$ rails server
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.1.8 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Notice: server is listening on all interfaces (0.0.0.0). Consider using 127.0
.0.1 (--binding option)
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
[2015-01-22 08:07:32] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2015-01-22 08:07:32] INFO  ruby 2.1.5 (2014-11-13) [i386-mingw32]
[2015-01-22 08:07:33] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=5848 port=3000


Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-01-22 08:07:54 -0500
Processing by Rails::WelcomeController#index as HTML
  Rendered c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/l
ib/rails/templates/rails/welcome/index.html.erb (45.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 388ms (Views: 309.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)


Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-01-22 08:07:57 -0500
Processing by Rails::WelcomeController#index as HTML
  Rendered c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/l
ib/rails/templates/rails/welcome/index.html.erb (0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 9ms (Views: 9.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)


Started GET "/rails/info/properties" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-01-22 08:08:02 -0500
Processing by Rails::InfoController#properties as */*
  Rendered c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/l
ib/rails/templates/rails/info/properties.html.erb (0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 426ms (Views: 65.0ms | ActiveRecord: 62.0ms)


Started GET "/rails/info/properties" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-01-22 08:08:27 -0500
Processing by Rails::InfoController#properties as */*
  Rendered c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/l
ib/rails/templates/rails/info/properties.html.erb (1.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 63ms (Views: 61.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)


Started GET "/pages/home" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-01-22 08:13:26 -0500
Processing by PagesController#home as HTML
  Rendered pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application (2.0ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 234ms

ActionView::Template::Error (File to import not found or unreadable: bootstrap.
Load paths:
  c:/Users/Doesha/Desktop/pinteresting/app/assets/images
  c:/Users/Doesha/Desktop/pinteresting/app/assets/javascripts
  c:/Users/Doesha/Desktop/pinteresting/app/assets/stylesheets
  c:/Users/Doesha/Desktop/pinteresting/vendor/assets/javascripts
  c:/Users/Doesha/Desktop/pinteresting/vendor/assets/stylesheets
  c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/turbolinks-2.5.2/lib/asse
ts/javascripts
  c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/jquery-rails-3.1.2/vendor
/assets/javascripts
  c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/coffee-rails-4.0.1/lib/as
sets/javascripts
  (in c:/Users/Doesha/Desktop/pinteresting/app/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap_and_
customization.css.scss:1)):
    2: <html>
    3: <head>
    4:   <title>Pinteresting</title>
    5:   <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolink
s-track' => true %>
    6:   <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => tr
ue %>
    7:   <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    8: </head>
  app/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap_and_customization.css.scss:1
  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:5:in `_app_views_layouts_application_ht
ml_erb___676133049_45098892'


  Rendered c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.8
/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (5.0ms)
  Rendered c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.8
/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb
 (3.0ms)
  Rendered c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.8
/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/template_error.html.erb within
 rescues/layout (141.0ms)
```

***Here's my application.html.erb file***:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Pinteresting</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>

<%= yield %>

</body>
</html>
```

***Here's my pages/home.html.erb file***:

```
<h1>Pages#home</h1>
<p>Find me in app/views/pages/home.html.erb</p>
```

***Here's my Gemfile***:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.1.8'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer',  platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

# Use debugger
# gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin]
```

***Here's whats showing up on the webpage when I run the rails server and try to load my apps homepage locally on the web***:

```
Sass::SyntaxError in Pages#home
Showing 

    c:/Users/Doesha/Desktop/pinteresting/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #5 raised:

    File to import not found or unreadable: bootstrap.
    Load paths:
      c:/Users/Doesha/Desktop/pinteresting/app/assets/images
      c:/Users/Doesha/Desktop/pinteresting/app/assets/javascripts
      c:/Users/Doesha/Desktop/pinteresting/app/assets/stylesheets
      c:/Users/Doesha/Desktop/pinteresting/vendor/assets/javascripts
      c:/Users/Doesha/Desktop/pinteresting/vendor/assets/stylesheets
      c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/turbolinks-2.5.2/lib/assets/javascripts
      c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/jquery-rails-3.1.2/vendor/assets/javascripts
      c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/coffee-rails-4.0.1/lib/assets/javascripts
      (in c:/Users/Doesha/Desktop/pinteresting/app/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap_and_customization.css.scss:1)
    Extracted source (around line #5):
    2
    3
    4
    5
    6
    7
    8

      <html>
      <head>
        <title>Pinteresting</title>
        <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
        <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
        <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
      </head>

    Rails.root: c:/Users/Doesha/Desktop/pinteresting

    Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
    app/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap_and_customization.css.scss:1
    app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:5:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___676133049_45098892'
```

Comment: Based on the error, it looks like you have a sass file trying to import bootstrap, but rails can't find that file. The relevant code you should be posting is your `application.css.scss` file.

Comment: from their wiki `// "bootstrap-sprockets" must be imported before "bootstrap" and "bootstrap/variables"` like `@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";`

Comment: I appreciate that! Been trying to figure this out for a while. Works great!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Did you run `bundle install` from the terminal and then restart the server?  If so, I think the problem might be what apneadiving referred to in your application.css.scss file.

Make sure that bootstrap-sprockets is coming first, like so:

application.css.scss

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try bootstrap-sass-rails instead of bootstrap-sass. It's geared towards use in the asset pipeline, so you won't have to mess around with importing bootstrap-sprockets. https://github.com/yabawock/bootstrap-sass-rails